# Getting one email instead of several in SAP

Tags: sap-basis

I created a job with several steps with the transaction `SM36` in SAP system and getting the results via email. For each step/report I am getting one separate email. Does anybody know how to combine all steps to one email?

Is there a transaction/report to combine several reports? Or is it possible with transaction `SM37` to get only email with several attachments?

Comment: how do you generate email? by standard SM37 means? show us your configuration

Comment: It's a simple feature, so you probably don't have a built-in solution to do more than it currently offers. You would have to create a custom program to send only one email.

Comment: I set up a "Distribution List" in SAP Business Workplace. This Distribution List I use as Spool List Recipient

Comment: Here some Screenshots from my configuration: https://www.imageupload.net/image/Tpeuc
https://www.imageupload.net/image/Tpa1W